# Copyright on mobile, clone an entire website

Tags: copyright

One person I know is currently building an iOS application, in the main page there are some icons where inside one of them he clones my whole website.

In the World Wide Web it's always a copyright infringement but on mobile, applications like Pinterest or Facebook leave you navigate through external websites without leave the application itself, so I'm not sure.

Clone a website inside an app, is it copyright infringement or not?

Comment: @JonasDralle he said that I must be happy cause all the traffic goes to me...but the traffic it's not the only thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### nothing makes mobile special

[If the website is actually copied, copyright infringement is triggered.](https://www.findlaw.com/smallbusiness/business-operations/is-it-ok-to-copy-material-from-a-website.html)

If however, the application loads your website from your website to display it, aka embedding it, then he does not copy your website. Copyright infringement is out, [especially in the EU](https://policyreview.info/articles/news/eu-ruling-embedding-does-not-equal-copyright-infringement/337).

However, if the embedding is made in a way that makes it appear that the content is the applications and only burdons the website with traffic yet no other benefit it could have, then other problems can arise - *stealing* traffic from the other site might constitute a breach of the CFAA. Also, the terms of use on the website might prevent such embedding, and a "don't embed my site" clause in the ToS would not be unconscionable, so the clause could be enforced in court.